# Background Color keeps going missing SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

This one is frustrating the hell out of me but I know that it is going to be a simple one once I figure it out.

I am struggling to get the background color of the whole "page" to be black.

```
    var body: some View {

    ZStack {
        
        Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
        List {
            ForEach(Experiences) { experiences in
                VStack{
                    ZStack{
                        VStack {
                            Text(experiences.artist).foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                            Text(experiences.albumName).foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }.background(Color.red)
    }
    .onAppear(perform: loadData)
}
```

If i comment out the List view I get the correct color, so the question is how do I layer a list view on top of a color ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define the background color of the list rows, and you can HIDE the default scrollview background, then define your own color:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<10) { experiences in
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("No. \(experiences)").foregroundColor(.orange)
                    Text("Album Name").foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .listRowBackground(Color.green) // background of rows
        }
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden) // hide default grey overall background
        .background(Color.red)
    }
}
```